# php code allways runs else and not if

Tags: php, authentication

I Cant login for some reazon, every time i open with
the testing file password exist, i have put an echo-test and mark it, but the code allways runs the **else** and not the **if**.

the kernel-login-logout.php is this:

```
<?php
$formusername = $_GET["username"];
$formpasswd = $_GET["passwd"];
$passwdget  = file_get_contents( "users/$formusername/passwd/thepasswd.txt" );
if ($formpasswd == $passwdget)
 {
  setcookie("libusername", $formusername,time() + (86400 * 7));
  setcookie("libpasswd", $formpasswd,time() + (86400 * 7));
 }
else
 {
  echo ("Password not found<br>");
 }
?>

<?php echo ($passwdget); ?><br>
<?php echo ($formpasswd); ?>
```

the url:

> kernel-login-logout.php?username=userdokimi&passwd=**testpasswd**&login=Login

the output:

```
Password not found
testpasswd
testpasswd
```

Comment: Your `else` is attached to your `if ($_GET["logout"] == "Logout")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo "'$passwdget'",strlen($passwdget); ?><br>
<?php echo "'$formpasswd'",strlen($formpasswd); ?>
```

to confirm that one or both of those variables don't have some invisible characters glued on to them, making them **not** equal.

You have a password stored in plain text (*and* visible in a Query String) -- that's very insecure, but we'll let that pass for the moment.

Comment: I would especially suspect a \n on the end of the line read from the file. Do a `chomp($passwdget);` to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You have code like this:

```
if A
if B
else C
```

That `else` applies to the `if B`, NOT the `if A`.

I think you meant this:

```
if A
elseif B
else C
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't assume the keys "logout", "passwd" and "username" will always be set.
You are also missing an **else** there.

```
if (isset($_GET['passwd']) && $_GET["passwd"] == $passwdget)
 {
  setcookie("libusername", $username,time() + (86400 * 7));
  setcookie("libpasswd", $passwd,time() + (86400 * 7));
 }
else if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET["logout"] == "Logout")
 {
  setcookie("libusername", null,time() + (86400 * 7));
  setcookie("libpasswd", null,time() + (86400 * 7));
 }
else
 {
  echo ("<br>Password not found");
 }
```